# Apache virtual-host not working correctly for subdomain

Tags: apache, subdomain, localhost, virtual-hosts

I've got a site set up on localhost that I'm actively developing, and I'd like to set up a subdomain on localhost to make my life 10* easier.

I added this to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost i1.localhost:80>
    ServerAdmin dummy@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/i1/"
    ServerName i1.localhost
    ServerAlias www.i1.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache stats up fine, but when I navigate to `http://localhost/` I'm seeing content from the `i1` subdomain. `http://i1.localhost/` works fine, however.

Then I tried doing this:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerAdmin dummy@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost i1.localhost:80>
    ServerAdmin dummy@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/i1/"
    ServerName i1.localhost
    ServerAlias www.i1.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But that worked the opposite. On both `localhost` and `i1.localhost` I'm seeing content from `C:/xampp/htdocs/`.

Anyone got an idea what's going wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Apache usually does not like a vhosts document root inside another vhost, try:

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"

and

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/i1/"